# I have an array with multiple objects in it and I am trying to run a check on an array inside those objects to see if all keys are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[{
  array: [{
    key: 1
  }]
}, {
  array: [{
    key: 1
  }, {
    key: 3
  }, {
    key: 3
  }]
}, {
  array: [{
    key: 1
  }, {
    key: 2
  }]
}]
```

Like you can see this is an array that has objects that nesting an array as well, the array length inside the object is not necessary equal to the other arrays
I know if it was regular array with just objects that has no arrays in them I can some or every JavaScript methods on the objects key but here its a little more tricky,
I thought about using for each and then every them?
Not sure its the best approach.

How can I check if all keys has the same value?

Answer (score 0):

##### Different solutions

1. Using Nested Loops:
   You can achieve this by using nested loops to iterate through the arrays and compare the key values. Here's how you could do it:

```js
const data = [
  {
    array: [{ key: 1 }],
  },
  {
    array: [{ key: 1 }, { key: 3 }, { key: 3 }],
  },
  {
    array: [{ key: 1 }, { key: 2 }],
  },
];

function allKeysHaveSameValue(data) {
  if (data.length === 0) return true; // Handle edge case

  const firstArray = data[0].array;
  const firstKeyValue = firstArray.length > 0 ? firstArray[0].key : undefined;

  for (const entry of data) {
    for (const innerEntry of entry.array) {
      if (innerEntry.key !== firstKeyValue) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}

const result = allKeysHaveSameValue(data);
console.log(result);
```

2. Using `every` and `map`:
   Here's how you could use every and map to achieve the same result:

```js
const result = data.every((entry) => {
  const firstKeyValue = entry.array.length > 0 ? entry.array[0].key : undefined;
  return entry.array.every((innerEntry) => innerEntry.key === firstKeyValue);
});

console.log(result);
```

3. Using `reduce` and `every`:
   Another approach is to use reduce to get the first key value and then use every to check if all keys have the same value:

```js
const result = data.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  const firstKeyValue = entry.array.length > 0 ? entry.array[0].key : undefined;
  return (
    acc &&
    entry.array.every((innerEntry) => innerEntry.key === firstKeyValue)
  );
}, true);

console.log(result);
```

##### Efficiency Consideration:

Among these methods, the second method using `every` and `map` is generally more concise and easier to read. However, all three methods have similar time complexities because they all involve iterating through the arrays.

In terms of efficiency, the first method using nested loops may have slightly better performance in some cases due to the direct loop structure. But the performance difference is unlikely to be significant unless you're dealing with very large datasets.

Comment: yes i did something similar with for each i created a side array to push to him all the boolenas from the every on the objects  mainArray.foreach(ob=>{sideArray.push(array.every......... }) and i every.sideAarray.... this will return true or false

Comment: Nice solution as well. If you found what you were looking for, can you mark the answer as answered?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if all of the key values within the nested arrays are equal for each object in the main, then:

```
array.const mainArray = [
  {
    array: [
      { key: 1 }
    ]
  },
  {
    array: [
      { key: 1 },
      { key: 3 },
      { key: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    array: [
      { key: 1 },
      { key: 2 }
    ]
  }
];

function checkKeysEqual(obj) {
  const firstKey = obj.array[0].key;
  return obj.array.every(item => item.key === firstKey);
}

const allArraysKeysEqual = mainArray.every(checkKeysEqual);

console.log(allArraysKeysEqual); // false
```

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate over the inner arrays and return the `key` value of each object, and then [create a set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from that array.

If the size of the set is `1` you'll know that that all the values are the same.

```js
const data=[{array:[{key:1}]},{array:[{key:1},{key:3},{key:3}]},{array:[{key:1},{key:2}]}];
const data2=[{array:[{key:1}]},{array:[{key:1},{key:1},{key:1}]},{array:[{key:1},{key:1}]}];

function everyNestedEqual(data) {
  return new Set(data.flatMap(obj => {
    return obj.array.map(inner => inner.key);
  })).size === 1;
}

console.log(everyNestedEqual(data));
console.log(everyNestedEqual(data2));
```

Additional documentation

- [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)